# How to extract p-values

Tags: r

I've been trying for a while to regress between the first observation and the rest of the 199 observations of my data set. I used the lapply function and the regression result is stored as a list in the environment.
My aim is to get only the list of p_values as a data frame and determine how many observations are less than 0.05.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
## Here are the code I am using right now.
myre1 <- apply(2:ncol(muscle), function(x) lm(muscle[,1] ~ muscle[,x], data = muscle))
myre2 <- lapply(muscle[,-1], function(x) lm(muscle$GIR ~ x))

## To extract the coefficient
myre3 <- lapply(2:ncol(muscle), function(x) coefficients(lm(muscle[,1] ~ muscle[,x], data = muscle)))
myre4 <- lapply(muscle[,-1], function(x) coefficients(lm(muscle$GIR ~ x)))
```

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-extract-p-values-of-regression-stored-as-list/62600

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/11117265

Comment: `dplyr::unnest()`? `as.dataframe()`? `unlist()`?

Comment: Hi Amare, looking at your code i think you mean 'variable' instead of 'observation'. As i understand this, you're trying to fit a `lm` with the first column as response and everything else as predictor, and then sort out which of those predictors actually *explain* the response. If i got this right, i suggest you try `lm1 = lm(resp ~ ., data = data); summary(lm1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You'll get the coefficients along with the p.values

```
sum1 <- lapply(mre1, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients)
sum2 <- lapply(mre2, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients)
```

You may have to convert the sum1 and sum2 to data frame.

Edit:

To extract the p values alone

```
sum1 <- lapply(mre1, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[10:12])
sum2 <- lapply(mre2, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[7:8])
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have posted a kind of example on the following page. if you have time please have a look at it.  https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-extract-p-values-of-regression-stored-as-list/62600

Comment: @AmareWolide do you want to extract the p values of the coefficients or the f-statistics?

Comment: @AmareWolide Check my updated answer and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have checked and it looks good but can we extract the p-value of the coefficient only?

Comment: @AmareWolide I tried referencing the p.values directly from the list, but I couldn't get it. Anyway, I have updated the code once again for extracting the p.values from the coefficients frame.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort to help me!